# Path.GetTempPath() unexpected symbol at the end of path

Tags: .net, path

I am trying to read Windows 2008 SP2 temp path using the code `Path.GetTempPath();` and get unexpected result.

Instead of

`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\`

I get

`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\`

Why I get "2" at the end of path? There is no such temp path on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this when remotely connecting to a server that supports multiple sessions: each remote session, even for the same user, gets its own temp path.

I assume this is to prevent temporary files from two sessions by the same user possibly interfering.

I understand that setting "Use Temporary folders per session" in Terminal services configuration controls this behaviour.

Comment: My work pc (which I do not connect to remotely) does this also.

Comment: The question is, where is this behavior documented.

Answer (score 0):

[Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) looks for the Temp folder using

1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
4. The Windows directory.

You might want to check the environment variables to see if any of those have a "2" at the end by mistake.